# Fibonacci in Haskell freezes pc?

Tags: haskell, recursion, freeze

I'm a beginner in **Haskell**, and I was trying to write the **fibonacci** function, but every time I run it my pc freezes. I have no idea why. This is my code:

```
fib n = if n<=2 then 1 else (fib n-1)+(fib n-2)
```

I don't know if it is of any help but I'm using GHC in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 5):

I think, you meant to write

```
fib n = if n<=2 then 1 else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

`fib n-1` will be interpreted as `(fib n) - 1`. That is why you have an infinite recursion.

Comment: I only wanted to add that, for large values of `n`, the above fixed code will be practically indistinguishable from the original involving infinite recursion, because the fixed code still has exponential complexity. For small values of `n` it will work fine, though.

Answer (score 3):

`fib n-1` is interpreted as `(fib n) - 1`, so you get stuck in an infinite loop, since you call `fib n`, when evaluating `fib n`. It will eventually exhaust memory since the expression tree will each time be larger.

You can fix this with:

```
fib n = if n <= 2 then 1 else (fib (n-1)) + (fib (n-2))
```

but this will still take exponential time. You can evaluate this in linear time with:

```
fib :: (Eq a, Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b
fib n = go n 0 1
    where go 0 a _ = a
          go n a b = go (n-1) b (a+b)
```